# Generics issue again. How can this method return correctly?

Tags: java, generics

I have a class called Custom and want to be able to have a method getAll(Class) that returns type Collection of Custom when it is passed the Custom class as an argument.

```
Collection<Custom> c = null;
c = getAll(Custom.class);

public static <T> Collection<T> getAll(Class<T> type) {
    Collection<type> t = new ArrayList<type>();
    return t;
}
```

Above is my attempt, but the compiler complains that I can't pass the class.  Is this the right way of doing this?  The reason for the types is because I want different classes to be able to call getAll() and have the calling class as the collection type.

tl;dr - I want a universal method that can take any class.
Thanks!

Comment: Collection is an interface, so you can't create a new instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do simply:

```
public static <T> Collection<T> getAll() {
    return  new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

and call this method with:

```
Collection<Custom> col = getAll();
```

I bet there is no need of argument `type` at all. It's working fine.

Comment: This compiles, it works, and it's the tidiest solution that's been posted here. It gets my vote.

Comment: Please explain if it should have the class argument or not.  I am confused with the conflicting opinions from the other answers.

Comment: @StephenD, Baadshah's code works exactly as he's provided it. You don't need to supply the getAll method with the Class object. I'm guessing the compiler is able to infer the type by following it back to the expected `Collection<Custom>` variable type.

Comment: Is there any need to pass the value or reference anywhere ,when you are not going to use it anyhow.??? Just no need in this case

Comment: Well, let me quote this person: "all method generics must be bound by the parameters of the function. – Anony-Mousse", meaning passing the Class.  I like your solution better, but was curious if this makes a difference.

Comment: Even if you bound with a parameter it will accept all the types of objects.So no difference AFAIK.

Comment: @Baadshah has this sort of inference been added since JDK 7 because I don't think I've seen this before.

Comment: @Arkanon Nope. In java6 I tried. I'm not much aware of Java7  :)

Comment: @StephenD And just to clarify, if the compiler can't infer the generic type you can specify it yourself. For example given a method `m(Collection<String> c)`, calling `m(getAll())` won't compile because type inference will fail. As a workaround you would do `m(MyClass.<String>getAll())`, where `MyClass` is the class declaring `getAll()`.

Comment: Try using `getAll().iterator()` to see a simple example where it fails without the `Class<T>` argument.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but your code is broken on multiple points.

```
Collection<type> t = new Collection<type>;
```

What is `type` supposed to be (at *compile* time - generics are implemented "by erasure", so they won't be available at runtime)? Try `Collection<T>` instead.

A constructor would need `()`, but `Collection` is an interface and thus cannot be instantiated... try `new ArrayList<T>()` instead.

i.e.

```
public static <T> Collection<T> getAll(Class<T> type) {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

works for me.

Here is an example of why the `Class<T>` parameter is a good idea:

```
Iterator<Integer> it1 = getAll(Integer.class)).iterator(); // Works.
Iterator<Integer> it2 = getAll().iterator(); // Does not work.
```

Comment: ah yes, sorry that was a typo.

Comment: The first error in your answer.  I should have made it into an ArrayList, for this example.

Comment: do i need to have an argument to this method for it to work?  ie, the Class<T> type?

Comment: Yes, because otherwise the complier cannot reliably infer what `T` is. This will get much more tricky when `Custom` involves generics on its own, because you can't do `Iterator<Bananas>.class`. You then need to cast.

Comment: Depending on your compiler it *sometimes* may work, but in general follow the rule: **all method generics must be bound by the parameters of the function**.